# Lua 5.3 - Integers - type() - lua_type()

Tags: c, lua, integer

Since Lua 5.3, inegers are supported.

But how can I do :

```
if type( 123 ) == "integer" then
end
```

Or

```
switch( lua_type( L, -1 ) )
{
case LUA_TINTEGER:
    break;
}
```

Since `type()` is still going to return `"number"` for both integer and reals, and `LUA_TINTEGER` does not exist ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lua 5.3 you can use `math.tointeger` to check if the value is an integer.
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.tointeger

> If the value x is convertible to an integer, returns that integer.
>   Otherwise, returns nil.

In C you can use `lua_isinteger` for the same purpose.
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_isinteger

> Returns 1 if the value at the given index is an integer (that is, the
>   value is a number and is represented as an integer), and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I deduce from this that I just can't use `lua_type()` in a `switch` and instead have to use a series of `if/else if/else` that uses `lua_isXXX()` functions, right ? The way they designed is seems really dirty to me.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that seems to be the case.
You can use one switch and you need one if statement for the number case to determine if the number is an integer or not. Same thing would be even for rpattiso's answer from what I can come up with.

Comment: @Virus721 You could always make a function that returns the type with number and integer separated and use that in the switch instead of directly using the lua_type.

Answer (score 12):

use [`math.type`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.type) for Lua 5.3

> Returns "integer" if x is an integer, "float" if it is a float, or nil
>   if x is not a number.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
--  Lua 5.3 'type' replacement.
    local typeRaw = type;
    local typeNew = function(I_vValue)
        local LR_sType;
        local L_tyRaw=typeRaw(I_vValue);
        if (L_tyRaw == "number")then
            LR_sType = math.type(I_vValue);
        else
            LR_sType = L_tyRaw;
        end
        return LR_sType;
    end
--  _G.type=typeNew;    --    Over ride global.
    assert(typeNew(123)=="integer",     "Error with 'typeNew'.");
    assert(typeNew(123.456)=="float",   "Error with 'typeNew'.");
    assert(typeNew("123.456")=="string","Error with 'typeNew'.");
    assert(typeNew(nil)=="nil",         "Error with 'typeNew'.");
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).